# CURL + SSIS filedownload errors

Tags: curl, ssis, download

I wrote a MS SSIS package to download a set of XML files given a URL. The SSIS package uses CURL to download these XML files as an Execute Process Task. I am reading the curl argument from a SQL table. I checked the curl commands manually in a shell and tehy all work fine.

I am passing the curl argument in a variable to the task by reading from a SQL table. It downloads some files but fails on some file. But when I take the exact same curl command and run manually in a shell, it downloads the file.

When I rerun the package, the execution fails at some other file and processes previously failed file successfully.

Error: 0xC0029151 at cURL, Execute Process Task: In Executing 
"C:\curl\curl.exe" "-o somefilename.xml "URL"" at "", The process exit code was "56" while the expected was "0".

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thank you,
Nagu

Answer (score 1):

curl error 56 is CURLE_RECV_ERROR, failure in receiving network data. This generally occurs due to a network problem of some sort, and the fact that it works the next time you try shows that it's a transient problem. Are you perhaps doing too many requests at once, causing the server to be overloaded and drop some connections? You could add the --retry option to have curl automatically perform that operation again if such an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks you very much Dan. I tried with curl retry option and also introduced a pause between two successive curl calls but I still get the same error.